# Hide packages inside my flutter app in LicensePage

Tags: flutter

I'm using the build in LicensePage class to show all my dependencies licenses.

But it also shows the sub packages inside of my app folder. Is there a way to hide them in the list?

I tried to set `publish_to: none` in each pubspec.yml file from the packages .. but it doesn't work.

The LicenseRegistry has a addLicense method. But there is no removeLicense or something else.

Is there any way to hide packages inside my app from the LicensePage overview?

Comment: Legally, you mostly need to have the licenses of the sub package you use displayed somewhere in your app. Most pub package are likely using the BSD 3-clause license which requires the license to be accessible. This doesn't answer your question, but note that what you're doing is likely violating the license terms.

Comment: but if the packages are part of my own code I think they should be under the same license like the whole app.... they gives my code only a structure ... i don't want to show  my folder structure inside my app (separated in packages) ... it is enough  to show one license for all my code.